# Outdoor smart plug with real-time energy monitoring and notification

Tags: smart-plugs, energy-monitoring-systems

I live in Australia. I have a garden bore with an electric bore pump for garden reticulation (irrigation). The bore supplies water to taps (faucets) in the garden, as well as sprinklers that are on separate timers. Consequently, power is continually supplied to the pump. On rare occasions one of the fittings snaps, as happened this morning, and water just continuously pumps out until we become aware of the breakage. This is bad enough if we are at home, but should it happen when no one is at home the pump might run for hours or even days. I could just put the bore pump on a smart plug and restrict the time that the power is supplied to the pump to the times required by the sprinklers, but that would mean manually turning on the power if we wanted to use a tap. What I would like is an outdoor smart plug that could not only remotely control power to the pump, but could also notify me when power is being consumed outside specified times. That way I could leave the power on all the time, as I currently do, but if I get a notification that power is being drawn at an unexpected time I could remotely turn the power off.

Has anyone come across a smart plug with this capability?

Comment: I wonder why you really need an outdoor plug: surely that circuit is separate on your electric panel and you could use a smart switch directly on the panel? There are also controllable water valves which could be another option. Do you currently have any smart home equipment/network, which would dictate one technology over another (e.g. Zigbee, Z-Wave…)

Comment: No, not a separate circuit. This is just a residential unit and is plugged into a GPO on one of the house power circuits. I don’t have anything beyond off-the-shelf smart plugs, smart globes, and Google Home devices.

Comment: I don’t know the regulations in Australia, but here in France in any place built or renovated in the last few decades, you have separate circuits for each major appliance, several for lighting, others for power outlets (often split per room), all with their own breaker on the electrical panel. I have 20 breakers on the electrical panel in my flat, not counting ground fault breakers. Is it not the case in your place?

Comment: No. I have a fairly large house with a large workshop/shed, and I have five general power circuits, two lights circuits, one circuit for the oven and one for the a/c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumptions:

I think the pump is always supplied with power today and its work is to pressurize the supply at the output so that the faucets and the timed sprinklers can do their work at the times they need to.

If that is true, you are looking for a solution that detects when there is a break in the fittings which would result in a loss of that pressure.

If those chain of assumptions is true, then, maybe something like this would be a solution for you. (I am not affiliated in any way to this product. Just using it as an example. There are many others that are in the same solution space.)

[https://www.amazon.com/Moen-900-006-1-Inch-Smart-Shutoff/dp/B081HT5LD6/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081HT5LD6)

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. This is definitely an interesting option. Thanks.

Comment: @Grant156, I'm glad you think that idea holds water !  Additionally, in stackexchange, you can mark answers as useful (or accepted) to help future readers (sometimes years from now !) The UI for doing that is to the immediate left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Fibaro Home Centre for my automation.  As part of that I am using the [Aeotec Heavy Duty Switch](https://aeotec.com/products/aeoteo-heavy-duty-switch/).  It is for indoor and outdoor use.  I have 2 outside and 2 inside the house.  And they work brilliantly.  These will also give you power consumption.  And being water proof, you don't need to enclose then in another box.

To program and activate it you will need some "server" software capable of zwave.  I am using the Fibaro dedicated server.  But you can use any software/hardware combo that supports zwave.  The most economical way is to buy an [Aeotec Z-Stick](https://aeotec.com/products/aeotec-z-stick-gen5/).  This is a USB stick with zwave hardware on it and you can simply plug it into your PC.  And there are a bunch of free software that you can run.

Disclaimer, I am not associated with either of the companies.

Blurb from Heavy Duty Switch

> Your high-powered utilities and  services don't  always  have to be turned on.   They don't always have to be costing you  money.  With  Heavy  Duty  Smart  Switch you'll have full control of them. You'll have the ability to wirelessly turn them on or off using Z-Wave  .  You'll  be able to do it remotely  and you'll be  able to do it  with an  automatic  schedule.  You'll also be able to save money immediately   when   you   use   Heavy  Duty  Smart  Switch's  inbuilt  energy   monitoring capabilities.  You'll  receive  real-time  reports  of  just  how  much  electricity  you're  paying  for.   You'll  then  be  able  to  use  scheduling  and automatic  controls  to reduce the money you spend on appliances that need  up to 40 amps of power.

Blurb from Z-Stick

> together in order to control and automate them. With Aeotec’s Z-Stick Gen5+ your gateway no longer needs to be expensive. Nor does it need to be a security or privacy risk. Z-Stick Gen5+ lets you build your own, locally hosted gateway. A gateway that is cloud free and that offers the features and security that are just right for you and your individual vision.
>
> Z-Stick Gen5+ has long been the Z-Wave community’s USB tool for building a gateway hub. It’s a best-seller because of its compatibility, its quality, and its functionalities. This new, 2020, plus-model brings a whole new array of compatibility and functionality to a USB stick already powering over 100,000 smart homes.

BTW, I am in NZ, this is good for 220V-240V

Comment: Thanks. Looks good, but I was hoping for something a little more immediate. Should I ever implement a more comprehensive smart home solution I’ll keep it in mind.